# How Can I "Solve Invalid content was found starting with element" Schematron error?

Tags: xml, hl7, hl7-cda

I have following request xml.

I did request the following message in return.

> [cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'telefonlar'. One of '{adresler}' is expected.]

I don't understand this message.

**My Request XML :**

```
 <component>
   <section classCode="DOCSECT" moodCode="EVN">
      <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.129.3.2.36" />
      <code code="KUDUZ_PROFILAKSI_IZLEM" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.3.129.2.2.2" codeSystemName="Veriseti" displayName="Kuduz Profilaksi İzlem Veriseti" />
      <entry>
         <organizer classCode="CLUSTER" moodCode="EVN">
            <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.129.3.3.36.0" />
            <statusCode code="completed" />
            <component>
               <organizer classCode="CLUSTER" moodCode="EVN">
                  <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.129.3.3.36.1" />
                  <statusCode code="completed" />
                  <component>
                     <observation classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN">
                        <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.129.3.3.36.1" />
                        <code code="ADRES_BILGILERI" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.3.129.2.2.3" codeSystemName="Veri Kısmı" codeSystemVersion="2.0" displayName="Adres Bilgileri" />
                        <value xsi:type="ST">2.Sakarya Mah. Şahan Sok No :2</value>
                        <value xsi:type="CD" code="10338" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.3.129.1.2.5" codeSystemName="Adres Kodu" codeSystemVersion="2.0" displayName="2.SAKARYA" />
                        <value xsi:type="CD" code="5" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.3.129.1.2.424" codeSystemName="Adres Kodu Seviyesi" codeSystemVersion="2.0" displayName="Mahalle" />
                        <value xsi:type="CD" code="1" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.3.129.1.2.18" codeSystemName="Adres Tipi" codeSystemVersion="2.0" displayName="Sürekli İkamet Adresi" />
                     </observation>
                  </component>
               </organizer>
            </component>
            <component>
               <organizer classCode="CLUSTER" moodCode="EVN">
                  <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.129.3.5.36.2" />
                  <statusCode code="completed" />
                  <component>
                     <observation classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN">
                        <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.129.3.3.36.2" />
                        <code code="TELEFON_BILGILERI" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.3.129.2.2.3" codeSystemName="Veri Kısmı" codeSystemVersion="2.0" displayName="Telefon Bilgileri" />
                        <value xsi:type="CD" code="2" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.3.129.1.2.19" codeSystemName="Telefon Tipi" codeSystemVersion="2.0" displayName="Ev telefonu" />
                        <value xsi:type="INT" value="2662273399" />
                     </observation>
                  </component>
                  <component>
                     <observation classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN">
                        <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.129.3.3.36.2" />
                        <code code="TELEFON_BILGILERI" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.3.129.2.2.3" codeSystemName="Veri Kısmı" codeSystemVersion="2.0" displayName="Telefon Bilgileri" />
                        <value xsi:type="CD" code="1" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.3.129.1.2.19" codeSystemName="Telefon Tipi" codeSystemVersion="2.0" displayName="Cep telefonu" />
                        <value xsi:type="INT" value="5508690761" />
                     </observation>
                  </component>
                  <component>
                     <observation classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN">
                        <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.129.3.3.36.2" />
                        <code code="TELEFON_BILGILERI" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.3.129.2.2.3" codeSystemName="Veri Kısmı" codeSystemVersion="2.0" displayName="Telefon Bilgileri" />
                        <value xsi:type="CD" code="3" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.3.129.1.2.19" codeSystemName="Telefon Tipi" codeSystemVersion="2.0" displayName="İş telefonu" />
                        <value xsi:type="INT" value="2662273399" />
                     </observation>
                  </component>
               </organizer>
            </component>
            <component>
               <observation classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN">
                  <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.129.3.4.242" />
                  <code code="KUDUZ_PROFILAKSISI_TAMAMLANMA_DURUMU" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.3.129.2.2.7" codeSystemName="Veri Elemanı" codeSystemVersion="2.0" displayName="Kuduz Profilaksisi Tamamlanma Durumu" />
                  <value xsi:type="CD" code="2" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.3.129.1.2.242" codeSystemName="Kuduz Profilaksisi Tamamlanma Durumu" codeSystemVersion="2.0" displayName="Kuduz profilaksisi devam ediyor" />
               </observation>
            </component>
            <component>
               <organizer classCode="CLUSTER" moodCode="EVN">
                  <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.129.3.5.36.362" />
                  <statusCode code="completed" />
                  <component>
                     <observation classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN">
                        <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.129.3.4.362" />
                        <code code="UYGULANAN_KUDUZ_PROFILAKSISI" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.3.129.2.2.7" codeSystemName="Veri Elemanı" codeSystemVersion="2.0" displayName="Uygulanan Kuduz Profilaksisi" />
                        <value xsi:type="CD" code="1" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.3.129.1.2.362" codeSystemName="Uygulanan Kuduz Profilaksisi" codeSystemVersion="2.0" displayName="Kuduz antiserumu yapıldı" />
                     </observation>
                  </component>
                  <component>
                     <observation classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN">
                        <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.129.3.4.362" />
                        <code code="UYGULANAN_KUDUZ_PROFILAKSISI" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.3.129.2.2.7" codeSystemName="Veri Elemanı" codeSystemVersion="2.0" displayName="Uygulanan Kuduz Profilaksisi" />
                        <value xsi:type="CD" code="10" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.3.129.1.2.362" codeSystemName="Uygulanan Kuduz Profilaksisi" codeSystemVersion="2.0" displayName="Kuduz şüpheli temas sonrası 6. doz kuduz aşısı yapıldı" />
                     </observation>
                  </component>
               </organizer>
            </component>
         </organizer>
      </entry>
   </section>
</component>
```

How should I edit the XML request?

How can solve this problem ?

Best Regards.

Comment: this cda seems well formed. If you want to edit any element in this cda..it can be done through normal xml operations without any hassle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

component => organizer => templateId  root values was wrong.

ok. I've solved